# help with my static class logic with pushing new values into an array

Tags: php

I am trying to make a class that will load my `.ini` files for me. The rundown is that I specify the name of the application I'm working with, then give it a single or array of files for it to load for me. Once that is done I just call it like so.

```
Ini::path(BASE_PATH . "config" . DS);
Ini::set_app("testApp");
Ini::load(array("db", "web", "themer"));
```

then I'm trying to use it like this

```
echo Ini::$get['testApp']['someKey']['someValue'];
```

at the moment I can use it without the `Ini::$app` being set because I'm trying to add that features. i.e `Ini::$get['someKey']['someValue'];`

My problem is that I cannot figure out how to push more `.ini` files into the `Ini::$get` array. The usage should be something like this

`Ini::push("anotherIni");`

that is suppose to call my `push` method and push the new file into the array. But I can't seem to build the array correctly. Either that, or it is not possible to push a new value into a static array.

My array with the array_push attempt looks like this ounce outputted with a `print_r()`

```
Array ( [testApp] => )
```

otherwise it outputs this without me trying to push the new ini into the array

```
Array ( [testApp] => Array ( [db] => [web] => [themer] => ) )
```

Here is my Class file (Updated to reflect answers)

```
    class Ini {

    public static $get = array();
    public static $tmp = array();
    public static $path;
    public static $app;
    public static $push;

    public static function load($file)
    {
        if (is_array($file)) {

            foreach ($file as $ini)
                self::$get[self::$app][$ini] = parse_ini_file(self::$path . $ini . ".ini", true);

            //array_push(self::$get[self::$app], "testIni");
        } else {

            self::$get[self::$app][$file] = parse_ini_file(self::$path . $file . ".ini", true);
        }
    }

    public static function push($file)
    {
        self::$tmp[$file] = parse_ini_file(self::$path . $file . ".ini", true);
        array_push(self::$get[self::$app], self::$tmp[$file]);
    }

    public static function set_app($name)
    {
        self::$app = $name;
        self::$get[self::$app] = array();
    }

    public static function path($path)
    {
        self::$path = $path;
        return self::$path;
    }

    // TODO: Create 'write', 'delete', 'append' function to change ini values
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer your question, but IMHO there are several major concerns with your code:

- Why is everything static? It would make more sense if the ini config was in an object. And if you just want to force its uniqueness, read about the singleton pattern.
- The purpose of your `$app` static property is obscure. It needs to be initialized before loading or reading files. That's almost unreadable. At the very least, your code would be more clear with a method `setDefaultApp($appName)` instead of setting directly this attribute.
- There are two syntaxes for adding an element `$e` at the end of an array `$a`:

  ```
  $a[] = $e;
  array_push($a, $e); // scarcely used
  ```

  With the latter syntax, `$a` has to be an array, [it won't be initialized](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php). So use the alternative syntax:

  ```
  self::$get[self::$app][] = $file;
  ```

  But I strongly recommend you opt for a more readable API. To your `echo Ini::$get['testApp']['someKey']['someValue'];` I'd even prefer `echo $ini->get('testApp')['someKey']['someValue'];`

Comment: heh, i tried to make it object based in my first attempt but i remembered i had an issue where if i needed this information on another page i didn't want to make a new object and reset the data. I read up singletons but saw that they work the same as static classes but with less code.

Comment: I'm afraid you have some misconception about PHP. With the Apache PHP module, each web page is independent. The variables are always deleted at the end of a request. So you won't be able to declare an object in one page and use it in another (by _page_, I mean _web page in response to a user request_, it can be in the same file or not). If you do not want to parse the ini files on each request, you have to use a cache, like APC or memcache.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in this line:

```
array_push(self::$get[self::$app], $file);
```

`array_push()` expects an array as it's first argument. I copy-pasted your class in to a PHP file, and then used the following code:

```
Ini::$app = 'Some App';

Ini::push('something.ini');
```

and receive the "`array_push()` expects..." error. This is because `self::$get[self::$app]` is a *string*, not an array.

So, you need a method that sets the first entry of the `$get` array to have a key of `self::$app` and a value of a blank array. This addtional method fixed it for me:

```
public static function set_app_name($name)
{
  self::$app = $name;
  self::$get[self::$app] = array();
}
```

Then use

```
Ini::set_app_name('Some App');
```

Comment: ya, i wasn't using the push() yet so i forgot to fix it prior to posting the code here. But i did go ahead and applied your example but didn't get any results in my array. i'm going to edit my question with updated code

Comment: Then your problem is in first line of the `push` method (where you're parsing the ini file). What error(s) is PHP throwing?

Comment: no error, it just won't push onto the array. I however am able to push if I manually write out the `array_push(self::$get[self::$app], "testPush");` but not by calling the method.

Comment: As I said then, you're problem is with the `parse_ini_file` line. I think you're being a little to generous with the scope of this question: I solved your problem but now you've moved the goalposts. I suggest you choose the best answer for your initial question and start a new question with your new problem. However, the `parse_ini_file` problem should be trivial to solve.